# Android Custom Keyboard Vertical Keys Not Working

Tags: android, keyboard

Currently, I am designing a custom keyboard for Android. This is what it looks like now:
[Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLli6.png)

However, the backspace and enter keys only type when pressed on in the upper half. Pressing the backspace key in the lower half results in typing a "6". Pressing the enter key in the lower half results in typing an "=".

What can I change so that the backspace and enter keys will function when pressed anywhere on that key?

Keyboard XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="12%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="50dp">
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="2" android:keyLabel="x²"/>
        <Key android:codes="94" android:keyLabel="^"/>
        <Key android:codes="4" android:keyLabel="π" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/"/>
        <Key android:codes="42" android:keyLabel="*"/>
        <Key android:codes="45" android:keyLabel="-"/>
        <Key android:codes="43" android:keyLabel="+" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="40" android:keyLabel="(" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="41" android:keyLabel=")"/>
        <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="√"/>
        <Key android:codes="33" android:keyLabel="!" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="⌫" android:keyHeight="100dp" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="17" android:keyLabel="log" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyWidth="23.9%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="18" android:keyLabel="ln" android:keyWidth="23.9%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="22" android:keyLabel="10ˣ" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyWidth="23.9%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="23" android:keyLabel="eˣ" android:keyWidth="23.9%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="⏎" android:keyHeight="100dp" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="28" android:keyLabel="ABC" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyWidth="23.9%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="29" android:keyLabel="TRIG" android:keyWidth="23.9%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:horizontalGap="4%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
        <Key android:codes="61" android:keyLabel="=" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```